# Server Performance in Non GUI Mode Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How can I measure the server side performance of server in NON-GUI mode, I have been running the server agent on the server side but still I am not able to generate any graph from server side in JP@GC-Graphs Generator.Can anyone suggest me a way toow to proceed on this .

Answer (score 2):

I have founded the way to Measure the Server side performance. By using PerfMon Metrics Collector which is an extra plugin from JMeter I can record Performance data by writing it to a file(JTL/CSV).

Steps

1.Add PerfMon Metrics Collector in you jmx file as listerner

2.Add the fields which you want to measure and in write results to file option, write it to a file in  JTL/CSV

3.Run the server agent on the server side.

4.Run the Test with the command prompt/ batch file .

5.After completion of tests you will be getting a (JTL/CSV) file in the configured location, you can open this using PerfMon Metrics Collector and can see the graphs.

Comment: what if server has unix based env, which is common?